# Strange error with double barrled surnames

Tags: bibtex, apacite

if I am citing the reference example I get S.H. Kim & Netessine (2013) and in the second example I get Laffont & Tirole (1987). Can someone explain to me how I make the first return the second outcome? I am using
`\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.

```
@article{kim13,
  title={Collaborative cost reduction and component procurement under information asymmetry},
  author={Kim, Sang-Hyun and Netessine, Serguei},
  journal={Management Science},
  volume={59},
  number={1},
  pages={189--206},
  year={2013},
  publisher={INFORMS}
}

@article{laffont87,
  title={Auctioning incentive contracts},
  author={Laffont, Jean-Jacques and Tirole, Jean},
  journal={Journal of Political Economy},
  volume={95},
  number={5},
  pages={921--937},
  year={1987},
  publisher={The University of Chicago Press}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This probably means you have another reference with Kim as the last name and the APA style requires initials to disambiguate authors with the same last name.

Comment: And I don't think there's a way to turn this off with `apacite`, at least not out of the box.  It's simpler to do this using `biblatex` and its `apa` style, if that's an option.

Comment: Thx Alan. You are absolutely right with Kim being twice in the paper. Unfortunately, I need lots of the nice properties that apacite provides (using & instead of and, for example). Isn't there a way to hardcode it with some trick in the bibfile or by creating one new command.

Comment: Lo and behold, yes. :) It's always fun to find duplicates which are your own answers and which you have no memory of writing. [Apacite: suppress initials intext?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/18954)  It even has Kim as the offending name!

Comment: Alan was able to solve it!